# Can BitmapFactory.decodeFile handle .ICO (Windows icons) files?

Tags: android, bitmap, icons

I am working on Android. Trying to display the "favicon" (aka "shortcut icon") or web pages.

So I already have the code to get the URL of this icon from any website, and download it onto my Android.

Now I am trying to make a Bitmap out of it, but always get null as a result.

The code:

```
String src = String.format("file:///data/data/com.intuitiveui.android/files/%s",prefName);
// prefName is "facebook.ico", and I do see tht file in my DDMS file browser. It's
// a valid icon file.

Bitmap res = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(src);
// This returns null
```

TIA

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of the [supported Android media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). ICO is not among them. You might be able to find a Java-based ICO decoder, though.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, too. But then I saw that WebView interface, so I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

SKIA library provides decoder class for ICO file. I was able to display an ICO file in the emulator. Haven't tried it yet in an actual android device though.

`Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/vlc.ico");`

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebView` component has a `getFavicon()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getFavicon()) so it's definitely possible to decode ICO files in Android.  You could [have a look at the Android source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/webkit;h=55fdba7c596b3989aabe85cdd6447cbf0ae8e9a6;hb=HEAD) to see how ICO files are parsed.  I've had a quick look but can't find the relevant part.

Alternatively, you should be use the SDK to get favicons for you.  However, I've had a quick try and can't get it to work.

For what it's worth here's my test code, noting again that **this doesn't work**:

```
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i("HelloAndroid","Loaded " + url);              
            Log.i("HelloAndroid","Icon " + (view.getFavicon() == null ? "not" : "") + " found");
        }

    });
    WebIconDatabase wid = WebIconDatabase.getInstance();
    wid.requestIconForPageUrl(url, new WebIconDatabase.IconListener() {
        public void onReceivedIcon(String url, Bitmap icon) {
            Log.i("HelloAndroid","Found Icon for " + url);
        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
    Log.i("HelloAndroid","Loading " + url);
```

The problem may be down to the fact that I'm not adding the `WebView` to a visible `View`.  If you do get this to work I'd be interested to hear what you did.

So sorry for giving two half complete answers, but I thought it was worth posting what I found.

Comment: Hi,

The funny thing is - I did manage to display the ICO file using:

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

when in is an InputStream of an HttpURLConnection.

This renders the ICO file fine.

But when I try to first save the ICO to a file:

FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput("facebook.ico", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
then reading from that in (InputStream) into this OutputStream,
I do see a file facebook.ico created.

But then when I try to call

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///data/data/com.intuitiveui.android/files/facebook.ico");

it returns null.

Comment: Hi,

I am aware of the WebView stuff. read somewhere it does not work.

Thanks !

Comment: @Shimon Shnitzer - Perhaps the problem is to do with how the files are handled rather than decoding the data.  What happens if use `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openFileInput("facebook.ico"));`

Comment: Now only thing that does not work is for some websites my code can find the ICO file info, and for some not.

For example - if I try www.facebook.com I can find the "shortcut icon" field and read the ICO location from there (you can try this by browsing to www.facebook.com on your PC, then view html source).

For other websites - e.g. www.google.com - I can't find the "shortcut icon" field at all...

Comment: By default the Favicon is at /favicon.ico - e.g. http://www.google.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work for Google and facebook and...
But is this the standard ?
Or do i just first check this, and if it's not there - try to read the link ?

Comment: I would check for the link and if no location is specified look for the FavIcon it in the root directory.  Have a look at Wikipedia for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. BitmapFactory.decode decoded *.ico on emulator but not on my Galaxy S. Solution for me was:

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int read=0;
                while((read = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                     bos.write(read);
                }

                byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray(); 
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length);//new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
```

Answer (score 0):

No accepted answer util now, I will share my findings here.

Windows .ico file format is a little complicated, it might contains one or more small images at multiple sizes and color depths, such that they may be scaled appropriately. Refer [ICO_(file_format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format))

So when using unix "file" command to check the icon file type, you might get the following result:

- *a.ico* : MS Windows icon resource - 1 icon, 32x32
- *b.ico* : MS Windows icon resource - 9 icons, 256x256

Note *a.ico* and *b.ico* contains different number of icons.

I tried to use **BitmapFactory.decodeFile** to decode these icons.

- Two Android devices with Android 4.3 can only decode *a.ico*, but can not decode *b.ico*.
- Devices with Android 4.4 or later can decode both *a.ico* and *b.ico*.

As I only have limited Android devices, I can't give any conclusion. Maybe anyone else could help.

So if you really want to decode .ico files, you may try:

- Create .ico files with only 1 image/picture in it
- Write your own .ico decoder or 3rd library like [image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with this since **Picasso** didn't seem to parse .ico files.
Surprisingly however, the solution is fairly simple.

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL("https://" + domain + "/favicon.ico").openStream();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

For me, this solution works with most of the websites but produces an empty bitmap whenever the size of the icon file is exceptionally low.