# Reading ICO file in android along with all sub-images

Tags: android, ico, image4j

I have found [Is there a way to decode a .ICO file to a resolution bigger than 16x16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678848/is-there-a-way-to-decode-a-ico-file-to-a-resolution-bigger-than-16x16?rq=1) from 2 years ago and the best suggestion was to use image4j. Unfortunately it does not work under android in particular (also), because the classes "IndexColorModel", "BufferedImage" and "WritableRaster" are not available.

While working around "BufferedImage" by replacing it with "Bitmap" may perhaps work and not using "WritableRaster", but instead setting individual (or a group of) pixels using setPixel may work as well, I cannot manage to replace "IndexColorModel", because I cannot wrap my head around it.

I am currently downloading a favicon from a website, which stores usually more than one image inside of it. The images are of different size. I read up on the structure of ICO files and analyzed image4j as much as I could. Yet I have troubles refactoring the various classes to not use AWT.

BitmapFactory is able to load ICO files; unfortunately it only loads the first image (this is my guess at least) and thus does not let me decide which image to load (let alone load them all and let me chose).

**Does anyone know if anything changed from 2 years ago and/or would anyone be willing to help me refactor e.g. BMPDecoder from image4j?** Or is there perhaps a totally different, easier approach to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a library based on image4j that will allow reading ICO files into a List of Bitmap-objects. In contrast to image4j ico4a does not use any AWT-classes, but instead only makes use of Bitmap / Bitmap.createBitmap.

See https://github.com/divStar/ico4a .

While the library's performance might not be the best as it uses a Bitmap-object's setPixel method in a loop, it gets the work done and it's good enough for me.

In comparison to image4j my library (ico4a) only decodes/reads files. While saving ICO files could be done probably relatively easy, I have not done so since I do not need it myself.

If you have further questions or issues with the library, post them on gitHub and I will see if I can help.