# Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); gives dimension 0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap, android-bitmap

Am trying to decode the bitmap using BitmapFactory,but it gives me height and width of output bitmap equal to 0.Could some help me out.My code is as follows.

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bFile, 0, bFile.length);
 System.out.println("heigth => "myBitmap.getHeight() + "  width  => " + myBitmap.getWidth());
```

where bFile is the byte array generated from .ico file.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have a look at this question and set of answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690503/can-bitmapfactory-decodefile-handle-ico-windows-icons-files  Im not completely sure Android OS by itself supports ico files

Answer (score 0):

try to do as follows

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.png", options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;
```

Comment: No luck Jitesh .Still it giving dimes as 0.The image file I'm trying to read is .ico file.I updated question.